# How do you properly remove an element from an array in c++?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int i, mid, fin;
    int x = 7;
    int array[x] = {50, 20, 90, 90, 50, 30, 35};
    cout<<"Original Array: ";
    for (i=0; i<x; i++){
        cout<<array[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;

    while (1){
        fin=0;
        for (i=0; i<x; i++) {
            if(array[i]>array[i+1]){
                mid=array[i];
                array[i]=array[i+1];
                array[i+1]=mid;
                fin=1;
            }
        }
        if (fin==0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    cout<<"Sorted Array: ";
    for (i=0; i<x; i++){
        cout<<array[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    int var=x;
    for (int i=0; i<x; i++) {
        if(array[i]==array[i+1]){
            var=var-1;
        }
    }
    int a2[var];
    cout<<"The second array has "<<var<<" values"<<endl;
    for (int j=0; j<var; j++){
        while(1){
            if (array[j]==array[j+1]){
                break;
            }
                else{
                    a2[j]=array[j];
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
    for (i=0; i<var; i++){
        cout<<a2[i]<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hello, I'm relatively new to c++. I am trying to figure out how to remove doubles from an array. I am almost done, but the program doesn't give the output I want, messing up on the last two parts of the result. I've tried bugfixing to the best of my ability, but I think at this point, I may just need help from someone more advanced. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: C-style arrays have fixed size and cannot have elements added or removed .  You can rearrange it so that the wanted elements occur at the start and then only use those elements instead of the full size

Answer (score 2):

You can't remove an element from an array. It is contiguous memory. Either you re-alloc and move/copy your structures or you should mark the elements as deleted by selecting unique value(by you) or another array for storing elements states.

Also note that, `T x[ std::size_t ]` is fixed-size array so its size is determined at compile time. So

```
int x = 7;
int array[x];
```

not possible, because `x` is runtime variable.

If you want to remove an element from the collection, decent way to that is using [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container). [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) suits your needs. If it is obligatory to hold values in an array, then you could use [std::optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) which allows to be value optional/nullable. So you can set [std::nullopt_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/nullopt_t) the value you want to remove, and skip those when printing the array.

With `std::vector` demonstration( you need c++11 at least ):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    // Filled with the values
    std::vector<int> data  { 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 };

    for ( auto val : data )
        std::cout << val << " ";

    std::cout << std::endl;

    // If you want to remove '3' from the array, then
    data.erase( data.begin() + 2 /* index of the element */ );

    for ( auto val : data )
        std::cout << val << " ";

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Output is :

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
>
> 1 2 4 5 6 7 8

[run online](https://godbolt.org/z/dzz-hn)

With `std::optional` demonstration ( you need c++17 for this ) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    // Filled with the values
    std::optional<int> data[ 8 ] { 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 };

    for ( auto val : data )
    {
        if ( val )
            std::cout << *val << " ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Let's you want to remove '3' from the array, then
    data[ 2 ] = std::optional<int>{};

    for ( auto val : data )
    {
        if ( val ) // If is not null, print then
            std::cout << *val << " ";
    }


    // It is actually not removed but not taken into account null values.
    std::cout << std::endl;

}
```

Output is :

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
>
> 1 2 4 5 6 7 8

[run online](https://godbolt.org/z/ihpEx6)

Comment: `T x[ std::size_t ]` is not necessarily a static array.   The fact that arrays in C++ have a size determined at compile time is unrelated to whether they have static storage duration.   Arrays of automatic storage duration are not `static`, and also have fixed size.

Comment: @Peter I meant its size by using `static` but you are right, it is misunderstandable, edited.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as it was already pointed out by others, your definition of the array is faulty. The length of a C-style array must be known at compile time. However, as I can see, you try to sort your array and then remove the elements. This is quite different form simple "remove doubles", because when you sort something, you change the ordering of elements.

So, here is the solution to the problem as I can understand it: *given a dynamic structure, like `std::vector`, what is the best-practice method of removing from it repeated elements, assuming that the order of the elements need not be preserved?*

OK. First let's start form the "array definition". The C++17 way of doing this is this:

```
std::vector v {50, 20, 90, 90, 50, 30, 35};
```

If you do not know, how to force your compiler into C++17 mode, aske a local guru :-) and temporarily use this instead:

```
std::vector<int> v {50, 20, 90, 90, 50, 30, 35};
```

Note that `std::vector` is the dynamic array that can be resized at runtime.
Interestingly, your code

```
int x = 7;
int array[x] = {50, 20, 90, 90, 50, 30, 35};
```

will very likely compile and run on many machines, but it is against the standard. Why it compiles? Because many compilers  allow this as a language exension. I guess GCC is one of the compilers that allow such nasty things by default. Unless you're really forced to, never go this way, always follow the standard, or your code will be not portable and may cease to compile any time the compiler is updated.

Oh, and avoid names like `array` as your identifiers, because this name is already used in the standard (`std::array`). Te compiler with handle it gracefully, but fellow programmers may not understand you.

Now back to the topic. Once you've defined the vector, you need to sort it:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Once the vector is sorted, you need to rearrange its elements so that the unique ones go to the front:

```
auto it = std::unique(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Now, you want to actually remove the doubles. Most people would do it like this:

```
v.resize(std::distance(v.begin(), it));
```

except that many would combine this with the previous instruction to omit declaration of `it` at the cost of some worsening of the code readability.

And you're done. The doubles are removed.

The main advantage of my solution is that I do not reinvent the wheel, but use the features already implemented in the standard library. This makes the code easy to read, easy to maintain and easy to understand the programmers intention.   That is, with your style solution, you would have to write a lengthy comment to express what your intention is. In contrast to this, my code is self-explanatory to even moderately experienced C++ programmer. And is only 4 lines long (with optional shortening to just 3 lines including the datastructure definition).